# How to silence warnings of a not fully implemented class

Tags: haskell, compiler-warnings

I declare my data type as an instance of class `Num` and implement only method sum `(+)`. The other methods like `(*)`, `negate`, `abs`, `fromInteger`, etc. I don't implement. The reason is I don't need these methods for my data type.

I compile the programme, and it's ok except some uncomfortable warnings such as:

```
Warning: No explicit method nor default method for `*'
...
```

How can I avoid these warnings, or do I need to implement the above methods? Actually, I don't want to implement them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can silence these warnings with a command line flag (in GHC)

```
ghc -fno-warn-missing-methods YourFile.hs
```

But if you only want to implement addition, then it is probably not appropriate to make your type an instance of `Num`. If you want just to have a nice operator for an operation on the type, you can define your own, you can even re-use `(+)` if you

```
import Prelude hiding ((+))
import qualified Prelude  -- so that (+) can be still used in qualified form
```

Comment: But if I don't want to compile my file outside, I want to load my file in ghci> , how can I add the flag "-fno-warn-missing-methods" in?

Comment: In ghci, you can `:set -fno-warn-missing-methods` before loading the file. If you want to pass the file on the command line, you can invoke ghci with the flag on the command line.

Comment: As an alternative to defining your own class or using `Num`, you could use `Monoid` with `<>` (aka mappend) for `+` and `mempty` for `0`.

Comment: I concur with @JohnL -- if your `+` is associative, you are probably talking about a Monoid (`import Data.Monoid` then `instance Monoid ...`)

Answer (score 3):

You can always use `undefined` as a placeholder value; its type is simply `a`, so it always typechecks. Be careful though, evaluating it will throw an exception during runtime.

```
data Foo = Bar | Baz

instance Eq Foo where
      Bar == Bar = True
      Baz == Baz = True
      (/=)       = undefined
```